# Install Ruby Gem + dependencies on specific folder and run that installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, fluentd

I am currently attempting to install on a specific directory a set of gem files and run that installation (trying to avoid installing to default Ruby locations).

e.g. I have a folder with gems I plan to install locally, thus I run the following command:

`gem install --force --install-dir .\install_3 --conservative --bindir .\install_3\bin --no-document --local *.gem`

This then installs all gems available in that folder in my install_3 directory.
However, I am having trouble running the gems I installed in that directory.

My question is, how can I install Ruby gems in a specific folder and make sure I run the gem and its dependencies from my specified folder in --install-dir option?

When I try to run with the following script:

```
@setlocal
@set DIRNAME=%~dp0
cd %DIRNAME%

@set PATH=%PATH%;%DIRNAME%install_3\bin
@set TEMP=C:\TEMP

fluentd -c fluentd.conf
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from C:/Users/yytcadm/Desktop/fluentd_1.8.0_gems/install_3/bin/fluentd:23:in `<main>'
        1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `activate_bin_path'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:284:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem fluentd (>= 0.a) with executable fluentd (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

Instead of fetching gems from my specified installation folder, it attempts to search for them in the default ruby gem folder.

Edit: It seems to throw an error on this line from my fluentd file:

`load Gem.activate_bin_path('fluentd', 'fluentd', version)`

I'm guessing I need to modify this to the custom path decided on my --install-dir option but my attempts have not been fruitful so far.

Answer (score 0):

When you require a gem, Rubygems searchs for it inside the default gems folder. You can prevent Rubygems to do that by adding the paths of your gems to the $LOAD_PATH variable.

For example, if you have one gem at /home/user/custom_dir/my_gem, you can do something like this before requiring the gem:

```
$LOAD_PATH << "/home/user/custom_dir/my_gem/lib"
```

Another option is to use `require_relative` instead of `require`. If you app root is /home/user/my_app and inside that dir you have the gems like /home/user/my_app/gems, you can do somthing like:

```
require_relative 'gems/my_gem'
```

Check this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0a5zv7uBHw it's really enlightening on how to require things.

Answer (score 0):

Providing answer to those that might need it:

In order to correctly automate the installation of a specific gem + their dependencies:

```
bundle install
bundle package --all-platforms --all
```

This will fetch all dependent gems and place them on vendor/cache

If you install your gem + dependencies with the following command:

```
gem install --no-user-install --install-dir Install_Location --conservative --bindir Install_Location\bin --no-document --local YOUR_GEM_TO_INSTALL
```

You can then run your gem commands by setting the following:

1. Add Install_Location/bin to PATH
2. Append Install_Location to GEM_HOME
3. Append Install_Location to GEM_PATH
4. run the gem commands needed

This allowed me to have run gem commands without these appearing/affecting gems available in gem list.